# How to align Lightbox 2 in the center of the page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, webforms, lightbox2

I am working on a gallery. Every thing works fine, except that the Lightbox Gallery comes slightly more to the upper side of the screen than in the center.

Lightbox source: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

It should dynamically place the overlay in the center of the screen, but for some reason it's not doing that in my case. When I debug the code it shows the main Lightbox container properties as:

```
<div id="lightbox" style="display: block; top: 189.4px; left: 0px;">
```

A second question: how can I also add a description of the photos to the Lightbox as right now it is only showing the photo's title. I actually need to add a description and date of the photos.

Just to make it more clear I am adding the screen shot to show how it looks on my screen:

![enter image description here][1]

From this screen shot it is clear the Lightbox starts from top:75 pixel, which does not make the image align in middle of the screen vertically.

Comment: I don't understand please give more details Thx

Comment: @Youssi, i have added screen of image to explain what i actually want

Comment: Your example link is dead, leading to error page: "Internal Error : /en/Album-Photos.aspx". No point leaving it around, if you find different link feel free to edit it back in.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem.  The vertical alignment is determined by the screen height but does not take into account the image size.  My problem was that pictures taken in portrait mode were overflowing the page, so I settled for modifying the lightbox code to move all the images up.  If you know ahead of time that all your images are the same size then you could theoretically alter this value to whatever you need it to be (you'd have to do the calculation on your own.  Look for this section of code within the lightbox js and modify it accordingly.

```
o=f.scrollTop()+f.height()/10;n=f.scrollLeft();this.$lightbox.css({top:o+'px',left:n+'px'}
```

Alternatively, in the lightbox css file, look for `.lightbox` and add the following:

```
  top: 0px !important;
```

modifying the 0px value to whatever you calculated.

To add a description to the lightbox, set the `<img>` tag's `alt` property.